# Why B''H instead of BS''D?

Tags: chabad

Why do Chabad Chassidim write ב''ה at the top of pages and most other Jews write בס''ד? I already know what these acronyms mean, I was just wondering why there is a difference. (ברוך השם and בסייעתא דשמיא, "Blessed is Hashem" and "With the help of Heaven")

Comment: Incidentally, from my experience, ב"ה used to be much more common, and only more recently, has בס"ד taken off.

Comment: ב"ה is be'ezras Hashem, with G-d's help, that essentially means the same thing, not as you wrote.

Comment: @Miriam - I've always seen בעזרת השם written like this: בעז''ה or בע''ה. Also my many Chabad friends have told me it stands for ברוך השם.

Comment: Closely related (near duplicate): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7137. Also very related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8093 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18630.

Comment: Ezra, I usually follow the same abbreviation scheme as you quote in your comment, but most people understand ב”ה at the top of a page to be בעזרת ה׳, rather than ברוך ה׳.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Yeah, I've always been taught it the way I mentioned.

Comment: my favorite was the rishonim who would write בגזרת השם

Comment: I haven't really followed this trend to verify it's "truth". In elementary school in the 60's and 70's, I wrote ב"ה on the top of every page. I'm assuming that since there is a general trend towards "yeshivish" in the U.S., and also a more "religious" trend among Orthodox, esp. the notion that Hashem is involved and affects everything we do may have gained more awareness and prominence, which is a concept better expressed by BS"D.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7137? cc @Fred

Comment: @msh210 Because this asks specifically about the Chabad practice. Perhaps the Chabad custom developed in some winding manner or has some degree of a unique provenance to the effect that Chabad's intention behind the acronym is in fact ברוך ה׳. On the other hand, I'm not quite convinced of this; perhaps this question is actually a duplicate.

Comment: there is no specific custom in chabad to write it either way. I have seen it done both ways.

Comment: Chabad people do write BS"D. In my experience, BS"D may be slightly more common on physical pieces of paper, or when written by hand, where it has a chance of getting scrapped.

Answer (score 2):

Baruch HaShem - is usually used when thanking hashem 
Bisiyata deshmaya or bezras hashem- means with the help of hashem so it's for when there is something that is a good action and your asking for hashems help. 
Im yaritz hashem- of hashem wants involves things that are either out of your control or when you are not sure if this is a good action.

Shelah parshas masay