# Where does the phrase בס"ד come from?

Tags: words, social-convention

People will sometimes mark their papers with the phrase בס"ד or ב"ה, I know what they mean but where does the idea of putting them on comes from. Is there and basis in the Torah or do any Rabbis have any insights onto this phrase.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8093/does-%d7%91%d7%94-actually-stand-for-boruch-hashem

Comment: Perhaps the custom originated from the Jesuit practice of writing AMDG at the top of documents, standing for _Ad maiorem Dei gloriam_ ("For the greater glory of God"). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_maiorem_Dei_gloriam

Comment: @ezra https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/bsiyata-dshmaya-or-baruch-hashem#comment83959_7137